# How to echo a WordPress tag inside PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

Inside my PHP, I want to append each wordpress post tag to the end of the URL. But it seems that it returns an Array and doesn't work. All my WordPress posts have only 1 tag each.

```
<?php
$tags = get_the_tags();
$html= file_get_contents('https://www.trade-ideas.com/ticky/ticky.html?symbol=')**.'$tags'**;

$start = strpos($html,'<div class="span3 height-325"');
$end =  strpos($html,'<!-- /span -->',$start);
$data= substr($html,$start,$end-$start);
echo "$data" ;
?>
```

Comment: `.'$tags'` will not expand `$tags` anyway, use double quotes instead. Use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on your array first

Comment: Instead of implode, you might need a loop ... we don't know what parameter the API you are using there actually expects.

Comment: `$html= file_get_contents('https://www.trade-ideas.com/ticky/ticky.html?symbol=')**.'$tags'**;` If you do as suggested by @brombeer Also move the `$tag` INSIDE the `)` Its not doing any good outside the `)`

Comment: `echo "$data" ;` the `"` are not required

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all I manage to do it

```
                                            <?php
$post_tags = get_the_tags();
if ( $post_tags ) {
$tags = $post_tags[0]->name; 
}   
$html= file_get_contents('https://www.trade-ideas.com/ticky/ticky.html?symbol='. "$tags");

$start = strpos($html,'<div class="span3 height-325"');
$end =  strpos($html,'<!-- /span -->',$start);
$data= substr($html,$start,$end-$start);
echo "$data" ;
```